# rememberLauncherForActivityResult on Result does not fire if I have rotated the screen, until I rotate the screen back to original orientatino

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that take a picture.

```
@Composable
fun MyView()
{
    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        onResult = { success ->
            Log.d("PersonView","TakePicture success=$success")
            //do stuff...
        }
    )

    //some where in the view
    val tempFile = createTempFile(context,person)
    cameraLauncher.launch(context.provideFileAsUri(tempFile))
}
```

The problem is, if I start from portrait,

1. trigger `cameraLauncher.launch(context.provideFileAsUri(tempFile))`
2. rotate the screen to landscape
3. take a picture and confirm
4. pop back to my app, `onResult` does not call
5. rotate back to portrait, `onResult` then call

How can I fix it so that `onResult` will fire immediately even the orientation has changed?

Comment: You can use configuration changed function with mutable state so you know that when the orientation is changed and on the basis of orientation changes you can call onResult and if you want code of that then i will post answer of this question as code if you want.

Comment: I end up doing traditional `registerForActivityResult` in `MainActivity` and handle everything in `MainActivity`, then just call a function from compose to activity. I consider this as a workaround and will appreciate any "compose way" to solve this.